# PHP Mongo's cursor speed very slow

Tags: php, mongodb

This code takes ~0.1s

```
// find
$benchmark = Profiler::start ('Testing', 'find()');
$cursor = MongoBG::getInstance ( )->setDatabase ('test')->setCollection ('testcoll')->find();
Profiler::stop ($benchmark);

$benchmark = Profiler::start ('Testing', 'cursor walk');
while ($cursor->hasNext()) {
    print_r($cursor->getNext());
}
Profiler::stop ($benchmark);
```

so "find()" took only 0.000017 seconds
but "cursor walk" 0.102812 seconds

Collection is about 100 rows, speed remains the same with 1000 or only 10 items in it.

Some server info:
FreeBSD 8.1, PHP 5.3.5 with (mongo/1.1.4), MongoDB version 1.6.6-pre

Comment: @mika: I very much doubt it took you 0.0005s in python to connect to DB and retrieve results. The above test is not representative.

Answer (score 4):

With such a quick time, it sounds like `find` didn't do anything but prepare an object (no communication with the database), and it's only upon using the cursor the actual query was executed and results were read. The cursor is doing the work which is why it's slower.

I know that's how the mongodb drivers for node.js worked. If you looked at it like that, the cursor speed isn't bad for opening a connection, authenticating, sending the query, receiving and buffering the response, then parsing/loading it into an object to return to you.

Comment: The word "probably" is not needed... :) It is indeed so. Function find() does nothing by itself, otherwise this would be *very* inefficient: `$collection->find()->limit(10);`. +1 for note on speed - the benchmark does not paint the proper picture (because it includes connection setup time).